# python : check if diagonalisable matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, diagonal

I want to diagonalise a matrix with Python, here is my script :

```
import scipy.linalg as lg
vp = lg.eig(A)      # eigen values and vectors 
D = N.diag(vp[0])  # diagonalisation of A from its eigen values
P=vp[1]          # such as A = P.D.P(-1)   
Pm1=lg.inv(P)
```

However I suspect A in not diagonalisable, but this does not prevent Python from calculating D, P and P(-1) without any trouble... What's more, the coefficients in D are complex numbers, is it normal when those in A are real ?
Is not there any way to check if this array is diagonalisable or not?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A` were not diagonalizable, the vectors in `P` would be linearly dependent. However, due to numerical errors they might be just very close to being linearly dependent.

For instance, consider

```
P = array([[1, 0],[1, 0.001]])
```

let

```python
Pm1 = inv(P)
```

Then `P * Pm1 - eye(2)` would be far from zero

```
[[    0.     0.]
 [-1000.     0.]]
```

Always look at the *condition number* of the matrix when computing the inverse. For instance `cond(P) = 2000.5` which is a very large number.

Also for some matrices the output of `eig()` again due to numerical errors may be very far from the true list of eigenvalues.

As for the complex eigenvalues, recall that a real matrix may have complex eigenvalues, though they will be in complex conjugate pairs. Since the field of reals is not algebraically closed, you cannot expect the eigenvalues to be always real, unless the matrix `A` is symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.is_diagonalizable). It has a function `is_diagonalizable`.

It checks if the matrix is diagonalisable.

Comment: This is OK with integer & rational matrix entries, but note that in floating point it has the usual floating point problems (and the algorithms used in sympy are not optimal for this case, much slower than np.linalg.eig). Consider `sympy.Matrix([[1, 1], [1e-100, 1]]).is_diagonalizable() == False`.

Comment: from sympy import Matrix as Mx
    if Mx(A).is_diagonalizable()== False:
        print "A not diago"

Comment: sorry I sent it before having finished. I added the code just above to try and got the error : "File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 1477, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError()" from the "if" line...

Answer (score 3):

Diagonalizable matrices are dense in C^nxn. What this means for floating point calculations is that rounding error makes matrices diagonalizable --- the result for `eig(A)` is `eig(Ap)` where `|A - Ap| <= floating point error` and Ap is diagonalizable. Standard numerical algorithms that compute eigenvalues will give such results.

Eigenvalues of a real matrix can be complex, e.g. for `[1 -2; 1 1]`.

Fully reliable detection of non-diagonalizable matrices can be done if you use exact arithmetic; in floating point you can perhaps consider diagonalizable matrices that lie "close" to non-diagonalizable ones as non-diagonalizable (see for example https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355912).

**EDIT**: one measure for closeness to non-diagonalizability in floating point can be obtained by computing the condition number of the eigenvector matrix, `w, V = np.linalg.eig(A); c = np.linalg.cond(V)`. If `c` is big, around `1/eps ~ 10**16`, the matrix is numerically close to non-diagonalizable.